# Before update trigger is not working

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I have two objects, which is used to populate the field value from product object to quote lineitem object. Both the objects have unique field name (`CPQQuoteLineItem__c`  --> `Product_Code__c`, product --> name) both the objects have same values in the field

for update trigger is not working

```
trigger updateproductcode on CPQQuoteLineItem__c(after insert, before update) {
    if (trigger.isInsert) {
        list < CPQQuoteLineItem__c > quotelineitemrecords = [select id, ProductCode__c, Product_Code__c from CPQQuoteLineItem__c where id IN: trigger.new];
        for (CPQQuoteLineItem__c singlerecord: quotelineitemrecords) {
            list < Product2 > testproduct = [select id, Name from Product2 where Name =: singlerecord.Product_Code__c];
            for (Product2 testpro: testproduct)
                singlerecord.ProductCode__c = testpro.id;
            update singlerecord;

        }
    }

    if (trigger.isUpdate) {
        list < CPQQuoteLineItem__c > quotelineitemrecords = [select id, ProductCode__c, Program_TF__c, Product_Code__c from CPQQuoteLineItem__c where id IN: trigger.new]; {


            for (CPQQuoteLineItem__c singlerecord: quotelineitemrecords) {
                list < Product2 > testproduct = [select id, Name from Product2 where Name =: singlerecord.Product_Code__c];
                for (Product2 testpro: testproduct)
                    singlerecord.ProductCode__c = testpro.id;
                system.debug('testproduct' + singlerecord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "is not working" is almost never enough to identify a problem. Please edit your question to add a detailed description of what happens, including any verbatim error messages and line numbers.

Comment: Actually, before you even try debugging, you need to refactor and bulkify this trigger. You need to move those SOQL queries out of the loops.

Comment: Also looks like the `insert` and `update` branches are _almost_ functionally identical. You have an opportunity to make your code more DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself, i.e. the code that is the same between your insert and update branches should only be written once). Looks like you aren't updating the records in `trigger.new` in your update branch, which could be your problem. I'd advise others to hold off on answering until you edit your question to include more details about what "not working" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to query the line item records, nor perform a recursive update, because you can modify the records in Trigger.new to save changes to the database. You should be querying all the product codes at the same time so you don't run in to bulk DML errors ("too many SOQL queries: 101"). There's no need to distinguish between a before insert and before update, even, since the logic should be identical.

Here's the revised code:

```
trigger updateproductcode on CPQQuoteLineItem__c(before insert, before update) {
  Map<String, Id> products = new Map<String, Id>();
  // Aggregate values to query
  for(CPQQuoteLineItem__c record: Trigger.new) {
    products.put(record.Product_Code__c, null);
  }
  // Query for record Ids
  for(Product2 record: [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Name = :products.keySet()]) {
    products.put(record.Name, record.Id);
  }
  // Update Trigger.new with queried values
  for(CPQQuoteLineItem__c record: Trigger.new) {
    record.ProductCode__c = products.get(record.Product_Code__c);
  }
}
```

This is just another example of the [Aggregate Query Update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern. It's very simple, yet one of the most commonly used patterns for bulkifying code.